# Is there a way to dynamicly take out HTML elements from a grid or flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Is there a way that if I have a grid like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

By applying a `.right` class some elements are taken out of the order and placed at the end of the grid and justified to the right (`end`).

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

The hardship comes from not knowing ahead of time how many `.left` and `.right` items there will be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox can do that with `order` and `margin` on the appropriate elements.

We can also leverage `:nth-child(n of x)` to select the first classed element to which to apply the margin.

> [Support](https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20%3Anth%2Dchild,instead%20of%20only%20type%20selectors.)

```css
.flexy {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

:nth-child(1 of .right) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.right {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexy">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item right">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item right">Item 4</div>
</div>

<div class="flexy">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item right">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item right">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item right">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dang - I should have first answered and then edited :P. But a good combination with `order` and `margin-left: auto`

Comment: I'm looking for something exactly like this. But how can I make it dynamic? I mean when the site renders I have no idea how many left- or right-aligned elements there will be.

Comment: Maybe something like  `.item:not(.right):last-child` would work?

Comment: Not that way but there is something new (not sure of support as yet) but I'll update now. Hang on

Comment: Updated, we can now target `nth of class`.